# How to preserve the timestamp of an io.Reader when copying a file by using a REST service in go?

Tags: rest, go

I am writing some microservices in Go which handle different files.

I want to transfer files from one service, the client, to another, the server, via PUT method. The service works, but there is a small point which is not elegant. The files I transfer are getting a new modification date, when I write them on the file system of the server.

At the moment I handle the `http.Request` at the server like this:

- ensure that there is a file at the server
- copy the body from the request to the server `io.Copy(myfile, r.Body)`

When I do that the file has the last modification date from now(). To solve this problem I could transfer a timestamp of the original file and set it via `io.Chtimes()`. But the request.Body implements an `io.ReadCloser` interface, so I think there must be a more elegant way to implement the writing of the file onto the server. Is there a function, which takes an `io.Reader` which preserves the timestamp of the file?
If not, is there a solution for REST services for this problem?

Comment: IMHO, it's useful to have the modification time data around (at least it serves you later when you need to know the timestamp at when the file is copied). I would probably think about how to include the legacy timestamp as an additional data. Perhaps appending it to the file and hash it or something similar.

Comment: it's up to you to transfer the time stamps and set the times you want on the file. There's no part of the http protocol or the "net/http" package to do this for you

Comment: An `io.Reader` is not a file and doesn't have any sort of timestamp associated with it. An interface is not the things that implement it.